# How can I prove the following statement and calculate the whole part of it?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms, natural-numbers, monotone-functions

I am currently trying to exercise for a competition and have the following problem for it:
$A_n = \log_{n}(n+1)+\log_{n+1}(n)$

where $n$ is natural number. I must prove that $A_n$ can never be a whole number and I must calculate the whole part of $A_n$ .
I also must study the monotonicity of the $A_n$ sequence.

I tried by converting the logarithms to the natural base but failed with it.

I would gladly appreciate your help in solving this problem, I am pretty stuck with it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "How can I prove the following statement and calculate the whole part of it?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: @Shiva  Given your propensity to edit low quality question, when such posts are closed, then deleted, points you gain from such edits go away.

Comment: @amWhy ok I gain points and it at least gives better look. Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
A_n 
&= \log_{n}(n+1)+\log_{n+1}(n)\\
&= \dfrac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}+\dfrac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)}\\
&=x+\dfrac1{x}
\qquad x=\dfrac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}
\gt 1\\
&=(\sqrt{x}-\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}})^2+2\\
&\gt 2\\
\end{array}
$

If
$A_n \ge 3$
then
$\sqrt{x}-\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}
\ge 1$.

Let
$y=\sqrt{x}
\gt 1$.

If
$y-\dfrac1{y} \ge 1$
then
$y^2-y \ge 1$
or
$(y-\frac12)^2
\ge \frac54
$
or
$y
\ge \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
$
so
$x
=y^2
\ge \frac{1+2\sqrt{5}+5}{4}
= \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}
\gt 2.618
$.

But,
using natural logs,

$\begin{array}\\
x
&=\dfrac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\\
&=\dfrac{\log(n)+\log(1+1/n)}{\log(n)}\\
&=1+\dfrac{\log(1+1/n)}{\log(n)}\\
&\lt 1+\dfrac1{n\log(n)}
\qquad \log(1+z)<z\\
&\lt 1+\dfrac1{2\log(2)}
\qquad (z\log(z))'=1+\log(z)>1
\text{ for } z>1\\
&\lt 1.8\\
\end{array}
$

which contradicts
$x > 2.618$.

Therefore
$2 < A_n < 3$.

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful. An elegant solution, simple but efficient.